# sort data frame based on date(preserving its format) in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have a data frame (df) in R that has multiple columns, say it has the following format

```
  V1   V2  date
  a1   b1  07/02/13    # a1 is a string, date represents July 2nd, 2013 here
  a2   b2  07/01/13   
  a3   b3  07/01/13
  .................
```

What I want is to sort the data frame in the order of date (earlier comes first), then V1 (in alphabet order). What I want is to preserve the current format of date in the output.

```
 V1   V2  date
 a2   b2  07/01/13   
 a3   b3  07/01/13
 a1   b1  07/02/13    
      .................
```

I tried to use the following commands,

```
df$date <- order(as.Date(df$date, format="%d/%m/%Y"))
 arrange(df,desc(date),V1)     # library dplyr  required
```

but this seems to change the date to how many days since 1970 (epoch times) and becomes difficult to interpret. Asking for help

Comment: Hint: Compare `order(c(10,1,5))` and `sort(c(10,1,5))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems: `?strptime` and `?order` vs `?sort`:

First, you should use `%y` for dates that are in the form dd/mm/yy (unless the dates are really 13 AD -- *i.e.* during Jesus' adolescence). Secondly `order(x)` is a vector of the rank of the corresponding element of `x`, so you were actually reaching for `sort` in your example. But you shouldn't use `order` or `sort`: `as.Date` imposes the correct ordering naturally:

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format="%m/%d/%y")
df <- df[with(df, order(date, V1)), ]

df$date <- as.character(df$date)  # though I'm curious why you need this step.
```

Comment: Your code creates some mysterious bug. In my raw data set, the date was from July 7th 2013 until recently, i.e, year 2014. But after your code run, I saw date start from Jan 5th 2013. some problem with as.Date function?

Comment: Take your raw data set `df`. Does `"05/01/13" %in% df$date` return `TRUE`? If so, that date is actually there!

Answer (score 1):

The function `order` only produces a sequence along which to index. Try:

```
df$date <- df$date[order(as.Date(df$date, format="%d/%m/%Y"))]
```

This will change the column, but you probably want to re-order the *dataframe*:

```
df <- df[order(as.Date(df$date, format="%d/%m/%Y")), ]
```